# updated test print file for modern workflow?

Tags: color-management

For a long time I've had a file from www.digitaldog.net that shows various test patterns and subjects.

But the other day when I was using it to figure out which profile and options printed best on my paper and ink, I noticed that the ColorChecker image reproduction was rather poor in some areas compared to the X-Rite passport.

I realized that the file, a jpeg, is S-RGB.  But my *printer* does better than that!  It’s sold as a “wide gamut” printer with hexachrome primaries, in fact.  My *monitor* is Adobe-RGB.  And the camera workflow uses files that are ProPhoto (In an earlier question I asked about why Lightroom etc. was using this as a default.  So using ProPhoto is something specific to a raw photo workflow and graphics arts industry people and web designers try and work in a narrow gamut; that’s why I’m asking this question **here**.)

So, is there a file I can use that is put together with the same purpose, but is made with ProPhoto color space and really shows information e.g. samples as you’d get with raw photos?

Even something that’s just a set of colorbars and ColorChecker patches generated digitally as pure values, stored as ProPhoto color space, would be helpful.

Comment: [Bruce Lindbloom](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/) has a reference image on his site that is computer generated, but it's sRGB - if you ask nicely I'll bet he'd add one in another color space.

Comment: I am confused here. What do you mean by "Color checker" and "Xrite Passport" because they are targets (In fact XritePassport *is* a color checker) A print pattern would be something Color Munki have. Of course you can print the pattern a standard color checker has.

Comment: @Rafael I print out the test image of the same colors as the Color Checker plaque. Then I examine the printed sheets next to the physical plaque, under good light.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use the [Gamut Test File](http://www.digitaldog.net/files/Gamut_Test_File_Flat.tif) from digitaldog.net?

Answer (score -1):

You can use Photoshop's "assign profile" action to assign any colourspace to the test file you have (which is sRGB). Assign profile alters the meaning of the colour numbers in the file, thus, the colour gamut is changed, just like you want.

Watch it happen on screen, assign ProPhoto and watch the colours increase in saturation. This is obviously going to ruin any image file, but would work on colour patches.

By the way, I recommend a visual test image, there's our Adobe RGB one here: http://www.colourmanagement.net/downloads_listing/.

Neil Barstow, colourmanagement.net

Comment: No... that will change the colors so they don’t match the physical test plaque.  And natural images like skin tones will not look good.  I think that would only be useful for step wedges to see how many of them are distinct when printing, but seems pointless for what I asked about.